# Need fit in LinearLayout icons on every device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, icons, android-linearlayout

I hope that atleast someone will try help me :)

I am beginner and sorry for my english.

My problem:
I need to fit this linearlayout on every device and I do not know how (it fits on my phone, but I think it will not fit on the others)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_middle"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_middle"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/elevation_card">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="66dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="clickLayout"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_icon"
                android:tint="@color/grey_hard" />

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Check in"
                android:id="@+id/checkin"
                android:textColor="@color/material_grey_800"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="66dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="clickLayout"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"

            >


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_icon"
                android:tint="@color/grey_hard" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add photo"
                android:id="@+id/addchillspotphoto"
                android:textColor="@color/material_grey_800"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="66dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="clickLayout"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            >


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_icon"
                android:tint="@color/grey_hard" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Report"
                android:id="@+id/reportchillspot"
                android:textColor="@color/material_grey_800"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="66dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="clickLayout"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            >


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_icon"
                android:tint="@color/grey_hard" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Rate"
                android:id="@+id/rate_chillspot"
                android:textColor="@color/material_grey_800"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="66dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="clickLayout"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            >


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_icon"
                android:tint="@color/grey_hard" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="WorkOmg"
                android:id="@+id/future_distance"
                android:textColor="@color/material_grey_800"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[How it looks in android emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiJBL.png)

**Thank you very much guys** for help, I tried my best but I do not know here....

***//EDIT:***

Here are results: (not working :/ )

[click here for screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiJBL.png)

Comment: can you provide screenshot

Comment: try use ```android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"``` for every **LinearLayout**

Comment: @danh DC not working :/ see screenshot in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only add `android:layout_weight=".2"` and changed `android:layout_width=".0dp"` for each `LinearLayout` because 0.2 * (5 LinearLayout) is 1 it's your `android:weightSum="1"`

try this code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_middle"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_middle"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/elevation_card">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/spacing_medium"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_width=".0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="clickLayout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_portrait" />

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/checkin"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Check in"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_grey_800"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                android:layout_width=".0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="clickLayout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_portrait"
                    android:tint="@color/grey_hard" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/addchillspotphoto"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Add photo"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_grey_800"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                android:layout_width=".0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="clickLayout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_icon"
                    android:tint="@color/grey_hard" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/reportchillspot"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Report"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_grey_800"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:layout_width=".0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="clickLayout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_icon"
                    android:tint="@color/grey_hard" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rate_chillspot"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Rate"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_grey_800"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
                android:layout_width=".0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="clickLayout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_icon"
                    android:tint="@color/grey_hard" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/future_distance"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="WorkOmg"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_grey_800"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Just replace the icons and title as per your choice.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tab1_icon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab1_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tab2_icon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab2_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tab3_icon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab3_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tab4_icon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab4_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tab5_icon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab5_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: what are the dimensions of icons you are using. I have edited my answer. Just pass fixed values to icon image views: 40dp in this case .

Comment: for example 192x192, but there isnt problem, I just need it to fit in :/

Comment: just try with fixed values for icons